# Select query takes long time even for 10 records from a very big records table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a very big records table about 6.5 million records. When I try to select some records from it even 10 records I have to wait a long random time.

```
SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5]
FROM [table]
WHERE deviceDataId = '640'
ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

My database is deployed on azure I also download and deploy it local system but it takes same time.

Query execution plan:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What indexes does your table `table` have? Can you post the query plan (using Paste the Plan)? Also, why are you wrapping the value `640` in single quotes? Is your column `Id` a `varchar`?

Comment: You need to attach your execution plan for performance questions [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: It is my `Id` column from other table its `Int` not `varchar`

Comment: Then why pass `'640'`, which is a `varchar`? Numerical values aren't wrapped in single quotes. Just have `WHERE Id = 640`. Though it's unlikely to cause any performance issues you should still be avoiding implicit conversion in the `WHERE` as much as possible. But still, we *need* that execution plan. I going to hazard a guess you have no indexes...

Comment: is Order By Required in query? Remove order by in query.

Comment: For an `OFFSET` it's required, @AmitKumarSingh ; otherwise how would SQL Server know which *order* in which to offset the rows? (Of course, as noted before, the column on  which the `ORDER BY` is on doesn't make any sense).

Comment: `WHERE Id = x ORDER BY Id` makes no sense; that order is non-deterministic since all rows have the same `Id`. In general, don't expect good performance when using `OFFSET .. FETCH NEXT`, performance tanks especially as offsets get higher. In this case it should not be the cause of your problems, that's likely a missing index on `Id`.

Comment: you have a where clause already

Comment: Hope your Id column has an index

Comment: CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_TABLE_ID ON TABLE(Id)

Comment: For the above, @AmitKumarSingh , the OP will also want to at least `INCLUDE` the columns `[Colomn1]`, `[Colomn2]`, `[Colomn3]`, `[Colomn4]`, and `[Colomn5]` in the index's definition so that it is covering, if they are creating a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on their `Id` column.

Comment: I have updated the query plan

Comment: What is the definition of the index `PK_Images`? It is doing a scan, which suggests that it is *not* on  your column `Id` but something else.

Comment: @JeroenMostert actually this id is not same this is here is fk of other table its not primary of the table . you are assuming primary key Id

Comment: @Lamu Covering index not a neccessity, because primary index goal will be to reach the rows, but agree it can speed up.

Comment: @Ahmad I would strongly suggest that if you have a column called `Id` in a table then it is a *safe* assumption that it is the ID for *that* table. If it is not, then i would suggest that the column is poorly named.

Comment: @Ahmad then write exact query you have, you just mixed 2 tables in one query.

Comment: @Ahmad: I am assuming nothing but what's in your *question*, and there is only one `table` there, so all references to `Id` must be the same. You are getting all rows with one particular value for `Id`, and then ordering those rows *by that very same value* makes no semantic sense.

Comment: I have updated the column name

Comment: @AmitKumarSingh the query is updated Please check it

Comment: Well then the question becomes "is there an index on `deviceDataId, Id` (preferably with the other columns you need `INCLUDE`d)". If not, a clustered index scan is the only option available.

Comment: Look at the amount of comments it took to get your execution plan and *real* query, @Ahmad . You mislead us for a long  time by using `Id` interchangibly for 2 different columns; that *could* have easily lost the interest of users and earned you downvotes.

Comment: This is first time happen to me in `sql` I checked execution plan for first time and then run it and take screen shot of it and then upload it that's why it takes time

Comment: *"down vote leads to ban my question that means I will unable to ask question any more here"* Then make sure you post questions that meet the expected standards of the site going forward, @Ahmad .

Comment: Standards here include supplying the at least the minimum amount to answer the question. In the case of SQL performance questions, you need to include table and index definitions, the full query, and share the execution plans via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/. If you don't give us what we need, we cannot answer. As it was, @Larnu managed to deduce what you wanted, but it shouldn't be like getting blood out of a stone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that we have your real query we can see that it *appears* that you have no index on  your column `deviceDataId`; meaning that the **entire** table needs to be scanned. As such, even though you only want 10 rows, all 6.5M rows need to be scanned and the value of  `deviceDataId` checked.

If you create an index on your column `deviceDataId` and minimally `INCLUDE` the others in your query, then you'll have a covering index which'll greatly help. This also **assumes** `id` is the column your `CLUSTERED INDEX` is ordered on.

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table_DeviceTableID_Cols1_5
    ON dbo.[table] (deviceDataId)
    INCLUDE ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5]);
```

Also, as I note in  the comments, if `deviceDataId` is an `int`, use an `int` value in your `WHERE` clause. Don't wrap numerical values in single quotes, that is for literal strings.

```sql
WHERE deviceDataId = 640
```

Comment: He may need one more index for Id column as in orderby to speed it up more.

Comment: If it's the clustered index, then we should be fine, hence my note about **assuming** it is, @AmitKumarSingh .

Comment: I am creating non clustered index and get back here after it .

Comment: yeah thanks non-clustered indexing work fine. Records get successfully. Is there any limit of indexing as well. How much size of record indexing work perfect in MSSQL ?